# Did I make any mistakes in usage of tenses?

Tags: grammar

1.They say that he **might not have done** all he could to keep her safe.

2.There are many things they **could have done** over the years to improve,but they didn't.

In the second case I'm not sure whether I used addition of contrast correctly.Maybe instead of **didn't** I should have put **hasn't done** or **did nothing**?Can somebody explain me how to use addition of contrast correctly in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentences sound perfectly fine to me

As for the second sentences - there are three ways to write it

1. There are many things they could have done over the years to improve,but they didn't.
2. There are many things they could have done over the years to improve,but they have not done it. (Has not is nt possible because the subject is 'they')
3. There are many things they could have done over the years to improve,but they did nothing.